# How to redirect to other page with JavaScript from sweetalerts2

Tags: javascript, html, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I got a web-based project from my school and I use sweetalerts2 inside it. The problem occurred when I tried to redirect the page after selecting a choice from sweetalerts2.

I want to show an alert when deleting data. If the user selects "Yes", then it redirects to another page. I've tried several ways but still no luck. Please help me with this.

Here's the code, When the result is confirmed, it redirects to another page. I've tried 3 ways (see the commented line)

```
    $('.swal4').click(function() {
         Swal.fire({
           title: 'Are you sure?',
           text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
           icon: 'warning',
           showCancelButton: true,
           confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
           cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
           confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
         }).then((result) => {
           if (result.isConfirmed) {
            //window.location.replace("mypage.php");
            //window.location.href = "mypage.php";
            //window.location = "mypage.php";
           }
         })
       });
```

Answer (score 1):

okay, the problem is solved now. I got the wrong JavaScript file.

The correct file

```
sweetalerts2.all.min.js
```

what I use

```
sweetalerts2.min.js
```